# PHP_curl loose content-length on redirect

Tags: php, http-headers, php-curl

I'm trying to make a request to payment processing page. This requires authorization, which takes place through a set of redirects. In the second step, I get "411 Length Required" error, which means that content-length was lost along the way. Indeed, I cannot see it in the log. What can be done here? Change tool (programming language)?

CURLOPT_VERBOSE:

```
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.dev.example.com (188.186.236.44) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.dev.example.com
*  start date: Apr 27 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.dev.example.com" matched cert's "*.dev.example.com"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=Sectigo Limited; CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /p2p/v2/payer HTTP/1.1
Host: api.dev.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Length: 224

* upload completely sent off: 224 out of 224 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 14:22:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 213
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=20
< Cache-Control: private
< Location: /api/payer/auth?sessionToken=e744a95992fa405ba10662bbc6908d6bedd48a73cc0d45d589f4ef2f7d7a0b88
< Set-Cookie: returnUrl=http://example.com/returnurl.php; path=/
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host api.dev.walletone.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://api.dev.example.com/auth?sessionToken=e744b95992fa405ba10662bbc6908d6b7dd48a73cc0d45d589f4ef2f7d7a0b88'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Found bundle for host api.dev.example.com: 0x5649fd243480 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host api.dev.example.com
* Connected to api.dev.example.com (188.186.236.44) port 443 (#0)
> POST /auth?sessionToken=e744b95992fa405ba10662bbc6908d6b7dd48a73cc0d45d589f4ef2f7d7a0b88 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.dev.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

< HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 14:22:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Content-Length: 344
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=20
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.dev.example.com left intact
```

My code is:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array (
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $curl_method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $order_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the content-length in the header, which would be set to the string length `strlen()` of $order_data

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array (
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
  "Content-Length: ". strlen($order_data)  
 ));
```

you can also debug this by checking out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);` which makes `curl_getinfo()` include the request's headers in its output.

Comment: Alice, as you can see in attached log, Content-Length in first request is present. It's absent in request, which php_curl make automaticaly and in which i cannot modify headers.
Anyway, I tryed your advice. Server didn't respond at all)

Comment: hmmm that seems odd. It's just a header like everything else. Oh sorry i realize i added a second content-type. edited my answer a bit

Comment: Another thing it could be is the way the authentication works. The content length is being sent in the first request but not the second.

Comment: If I'll remove "accept", then server will returns another mistake. I tooked this accept header from my Firefox. I realised this method with ordinary form and it works like a charm.

Comment: Another version is a problem with 302 "redirect temporary". I found an article (in Russian) that different http clients (postman, etc) lost content-length with this type of redirect. Solution was changing 302 on 307, but it couldn't be a solution for my situation. Anyway, loosing ordinary http header looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $curl_method). Curl tryed to swithc to GET, like mostly browsers do, but cannot. Use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); indeed.